# Running ajax query directly from url

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I use the checkbox in a part where I check filters with ajax. As soon as I click on the Checkbox, all products are loaded on the same page. I am trying to suppress the data here via URL without pressing any checkbox here. Is there any way I can do this?

Checkbox Data Here

```html
<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_34" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_34">Data 1 </label>

<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_35" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_35">Data 2 </label>          

<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_36" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_36">Data 3</label>

<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_37" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_37">Data 4</label>
```

This is the query I want to create.

```
https://example.com/kategori/gunes-urunleri?urun_marka=marka_36
```

**If you want to check it live You can access the site by** [clicking here](https://dermoevim.com/kategori/gunes-urunleri).

Comment: What do you mean by "suppress the data"? What you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @EvgeniDikerman When I press one of these checkboxes on my product listing page, the data is loaded with ajax without any url structure. I am also trying to pull this url structure. So I'm trying to bring the products of the brand in the ID that I have manually selected with the url structure.

Comment: I see that you removed the Accepted answer. How can I improve my answer to fit your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here on every change to some checkbox, the state is taken and transformed to search params string. You need to implement the `fetchData` method.

```js
function getSelectedIds(){
  const ids = [];
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.custom-control-input.common_selector')
    .forEach(el => {
      if(el.checked){
        ids.push(el.id); 
      }
    })
  return ids;
}
function getUrl(){
  const ids = getSelectedIds();
  const url = new URL('https://example.com/kategori/gunes-urunleri');
  ids.map(id => {
    url.searchParams.append('urun_marka', id);
  });
  return url.toString();
}

function fetchData(){
  console.log('fetching data from:', getUrl());
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('.custom-control-input.common_selector')
  .forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('change', fetchData);
  })
```

```html
<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_34" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_34">Data 1 </label>

<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_35" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_35">Data 2 </label>          

<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_36" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_36">Data 3</label>

<input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_37" value="35">
<label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_37">Data 4</label>
```